# Passing IplImage * to function, original not getting updated

Tags: c++, c, opencv, parameter-passing, iplimage

I am having trouble passing IplImage* parameters in functions. This is for a school project and unfortunately am not supposed to edit the files doing the calling to my filter functions. In the main, the image is brought in as a command line parameter, then a copy of this is made and passed to the correct filter function, as such:

```
IplImage * floating = cvCreateImage (cvSize (img->width, img->height), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3);
cvConvertScale (img, floating, 1/255., 0);

IplImage * filtered;

switch (filter.ImageFormat)
{
    case YUV24:
        filtered = cvCreateImage (cvSize (floating->width, floating->height), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3);
        cvCvtColor (floating, filtered, CV_BGR2YCrCb);
        break;
    case BGR24:
        filtered = cvCloneImage (floating);
        break;
    case Gray:
        filtered = cvCreateImage (cvSize (floating->width, floating->height), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
        cvCvtColor (floating, filtered, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        break;
}

cvNamedWindow ("original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage ("original", img);

filter.ImageFilter (filtered, p);

if (filter.ImageFormat == YUV24)
{
      cvCvtColor (filtered, filtered, CV_YCrCb2BGR);
}

cvNamedWindow (filterName.c_str(), CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage (filterName.c_str(), filtered);
```

And here is the code from one of my filters:

```
void median (IplImage * image, int k){
    cout << "image address: " << &image << endl;
    Mat matImage(image);        //convert IplImage to Mat for work
    vector<Mat> bgr_channels;   //vector to hold each channel
    int i,j,m,n;                //row/column indeces
    int kernelSize = (2*k+1)*(2*k+1);
    vector<float> vals(kernelSize); //kernelSized vector to hold all values of image
                //within kernel centered at a given pixel
    int vecIndex = 0;   //then sorted to get the median
    int chanIndex = 0;  //index used to for each channel

    //add padding to account for border issues with convolution
    copyMakeBorder( matImage, matImage, k, k, k, k, BORDER_REPLICATE);
    //split channes to do work on individual channels
    split(matImage, bgr_channels);

    for(chanIndex=0; chanIndex < matImage.channels(); chanIndex++){
        //outer loop for scanning entire image
        for(i=k; i<matImage.rows-k; i++)/*image row index*/{
            for(j=k; j<matImage.cols-k; j++)/*image column index*/{
                //inner loop for scanning image only in kernel boundaries
                vecIndex = 0;   //reset vecIndex at start of each kernel loop
                for(m=i-k; m<(i+k+1); m++)/*kernel row index*/{
                    for(n=j-k; n<(j+k+1); n++)/*kernel column index*/{                      
                        vals[vecIndex++] = bgr_channels[chanIndex].at<float>(m,n);
                    }
                }
                insertionSort(vals, 0, vals.size()-1);  //insertion sort from CSCI362 text, see references  
                bgr_channels[chanIndex].at<float>(i,j) = vals[vals.size()/2]; //new value chosen from middle element                                                                //of sorted vector
            }
        }
    }

    merge(bgr_channels, matImage);      //merge channels together
    imshow("Median: Mat", matImage);    //left this in becuase the original doesn't seem to get modified    
                                        //when converting the Mat back to an IplImage
    image = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)matImage);  //convert backto IplImage for DesktopMain
}
```

The problem is, that the filtered image shown in the main, does not reflect the actual image. It only shows the original image. When I output put the Mat style image matImage in my filter function, it shows the filtered image. Immediately after I convert back to IplImage and set the IplImage* input parameter equal to the the converted, filtered version. But the changes do not reflect the image displayed in the main function.

This is making it hard to create some of my other filters such as Gaussian and Sobel, because those filters themselves make calls to other functions before doing their manipulations, and I am not getting edited data back. Is there something I am missing in how to edit the passed IplImage* variable?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
image = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)matImage);
```

use this:

```
cvCopy(&(IplImage)matImage,image);
```

Comment: Yes, this worked great. Had some issues initially because I had padded the border of matImage, but stripped that and worked great.

Out of curiosity, and the need to understand, what is the difference between the two above. Both seem to be operating on IplImage* image. If I do cvShowImage("image", image) right after the cvCloneImage call, I see the filtered version. Why don't those changes to image affect the image from main like cvCopy does? Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @JoshPharis: You are passing the argument by value, i.e., a *copy* of the pointer is passed to the function.  This means that you can mutate *what the pointer refers to* and that mutation will be seen outside of the function, but if you assign an entirely new value to the argument, you're only modifying the copy passed to the function.  All arguments in C are passed by value, and in C++ you pass by reference when you use something like; `void foo(SomeType& arg);`

Answer (score 3):

Your function never edits the image that's passed to it.

This line is presumably making a copy of the image.

```
Mat matImage(image);        //convert IplImage to Mat for work
```

Then your code modifies that `matImage` copy.

And at the end of the function, that local copy is destroyed, and the `IplImage` pointed to by `image` was never modified.

**Edit:**
Vaughn Cato's answer shows specifically how you can address this.

Answer (score 0):

To go over the 3 channels you should use an iterator :

```
Mat out;
*********open out********
Mat_<Vec3b>::iterator it = out.begin<Vec3b>();
MatConstIterator_<Vec3b> it_end = out.end<Vec3b>();

for(; it != it_end; ++it)
{
    //your 3 channels
    (*it)[0] = ...;
    (*it)[1] = ....;
    (*it)[2] = ......;
}
```